# Why calling cv2.VideoCapture() changes the pixel format of a v4l camera?

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, v4l2, pixelformat

**The problem:**
Just calling `cv2.VideoCapture()` - changes the pixel format on a video camera.

**Problem description:**
I execute the following two commends, after which my `/dev/video2` camera's pixel format is '`Y8I` ':

```
$ v4l2-ctl -d2 --set-fmt-video=width=424,height=240,pixelformat=2
$ v4l2-ctl -d2 --get-fmt-video | grep 'Pixel Format'
        Pixel Format      : 'Y8I '
```

and if I execute the following MCVE Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import cv2

def query_current_format(video_device_index):
    command = "v4l2-ctl -d %d -V" % video_device_index
    output = subprocess.call(command, shell=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
    query_current_format(2)
```

I get the expected result (namely, the pixel format is '`Y8I` ' as expected):

```
$ python show_current_format.SO.py
Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 424/240
        Pixel Format      : 'Y8I '
        Field             : None
        Bytes per Line    : 848
        Size Image        : 203520
        Colorspace        : Default
        Transfer Function : Default
        YCbCr Encoding    : Default
        Quantization      : Default
        Flags             :
```

**However**, if I un-comment the `cv2.VideoCapture(2)` command, the pixel format *changes*:

```
$ v4l2-ctl -d2 --set-fmt-video=width=424,height=240,pixelformat=2
$ v4l2-ctl -d2 --get-fmt-video | grep 'Pixel Format'
        Pixel Format      : 'Y8I '
$ cat show_current_format.SO.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import cv2

def query_current_format(video_device_index):
    command = "v4l2-ctl -d %d -V" % video_device_index
    output = subprocess.call(command, shell=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
    query_current_format(2)
$ python show_current_format.SO.py
Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 640/480
        Pixel Format      : 'UYVY'
        Field             : None
        Bytes per Line    : 1280
        Size Image        : 614400
        Colorspace        : Default
        Transfer Function : Default
        YCbCr Encoding    : Default
        Quantization      : Default
        Flags             :
```

### Can anyone explain why calling `cv2.VideoCapture()` changes the pixel format?

**Is that so the format would be the only available non-proprietary format?**

---

**Environment:**
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Camera: Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 410
Driver: uvcvideo
Driver version: 4.4.44

**Camera's available pixel formats:**

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-formats -d 2
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Index       : 0
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: ''
        Name        : 00000032-0000-0010-8000-00aa003

        Index       : 1
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'UYVY'
        Name        : UYVY 4:2:2

        Index       : 2
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'Y8I '
        Name        : Greyscale 8 L/R (Y8I)

        Index       : 3
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'Y12I'
        Name        : Greyscale 12 L/R (Y12I)
```

**Camera's data:**

```
$ v4l2-ctl --all -d 2
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
        Driver name   : uvcvideo
        Card type     : Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 410
        Bus info      : usb-0000:00:14.0-2
        Driver version: 4.4.44
        Capabilities  : 0x84200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps   : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 424/240
        Pixel Format      : 'Y8I '
        Field             : None
        Bytes per Line    : 848
        Size Image        : 203520
        Colorspace        : Default
        Transfer Function : Default
        YCbCr Encoding    : Default
        Quantization      : Default
        Flags             :
Crop Capability Video Capture:
        Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 424, Height 240
        Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 424, Height 240
        Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 424, Height 240
Selection: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 424, Height 240
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
        Capabilities     : timeperframe
        Frames per second: 90.000 (90/1)
        Read buffers     : 0
 white_balance_temperature_auto (bool)   : default=0 value=0
                           gain (int)    : min=16 max=248 step=1 default=16 value=16
      white_balance_temperature (int)    : min=2800 max=6500 step=1 default=2800 value=2800
                  exposure_auto (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=1 value=1
              exposure_absolute (int)    : min=0 max=1000 step=1 default=10 value=10
         exposure_auto_priority (bool)   : default=0 value=0
```

### Edit 1:

```
$ v4l2-ctl -d1 --set-fmt-video=width=424,height=240,pixelformat=0
$ v4l2-ctl -d1 --get-fmt-video | grep 'Pixel Format'                   
Pixel Format      : 'Z16 '
$ cat show_current_format.SO.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import cv2

def query_current_format(video_device_index):
    command = "v4l2-ctl -d %d -V" % video_device_index
    output = subprocess.call(command, shell=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    query_current_format(1)
openstack@prclnx04:~/python/opencv$ python show_current_format.SO.py
libv4l2: error set_fmt gave us a different result then try_fmt!
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable convert to requested pixfmt
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl VIDIOCSPICT

Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 424/240
        Pixel Format      : ''
        Field             : None
        Bytes per Line    : 848
        Size Image        : 203520
        Colorspace        : Default
        Transfer Function : Default
        YCbCr Encoding    : Default
        Quantization      : Default
        Flags             :
$ v4l2-ctl --list-formats -d 1
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Index       : 0
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'Z16 '
        Name        : Depth data 16-bit (Z16)

        Index       : 1
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: ''
        Name        : 00000050-0000-0010-8000-00aa003

$ v4l2-ctl --all -d 1
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
        Driver name   : uvcvideo
        Card type     : Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 410
        Bus info      : usb-0000:00:14.0-2
        Driver version: 4.4.44
        Capabilities  : 0x84200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps   : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 424/240
        Pixel Format      : ''
        Field             : None
        Bytes per Line    : 848
        Size Image        : 203520
        Colorspace        : Default
        Transfer Function : Default
        YCbCr Encoding    : Default
        Quantization      : Default
        Flags             :
Crop Capability Video Capture:
        Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 424, Height 240
        Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 424, Height 240
        Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 424, Height 240
Selection: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 424, Height 240
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
        Capabilities     : timeperframe
        Frames per second: 90.000 (90/1)
        Read buffers     : 0
 white_balance_temperature_auto (bool)   : default=0 value=0
                           gain (int)    : min=16 max=248 step=1 default=16 value=16
      white_balance_temperature (int)    : min=2800 max=6500 step=1 default=2800 value=2800
                  exposure_auto (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=1 value=1
              exposure_absolute (int)    : min=0 max=1000 step=1 default=10 value=10
         exposure_auto_priority (bool)   : default=0 value=0
```

Comment: It could have something to do with Y8I being an interleaved format?

Reading greyscale cameras to YUV formats is easy because the chroma data is different to the colour data. But the interleaved format of Y8I would require more data to be written to store the same image. I would guess that UYVY was chosen to speed up image acquisition for greyscale cameras which are quite common in image processing applications.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @DeeCee. However, as you can see in (the added) `Edit 1`, calling `VideoCapture` also changes `Z16` format to `''` format in `/dev/video1.`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like currently Y8I format is not implemented in OpenCV videoio module. See the [source code here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp). The following source piece hints at supported formats:

```
static int autosetup_capture_mode_v4l2(CvCaptureCAM_V4L* capture) {
    //in case palette is already set and works, no need to setup.
    if(capture->palette != 0 and try_palette_v4l2(capture)){
        return 0;
    }
    __u32 try_order[] = {
            V4L2_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
            V4L2_PIX_FMT_YVU420,
            V4L2_PIX_FMT_YUV411P,
#ifdef HAVE_JPEG
            V4L2_PIX_FMT_MJPEG,
            V4L2_PIX_FMT_JPEG,
#endif
            V4L2_PIX_FMT_YUYV,
            V4L2_PIX_FMT_UYVY,
            V4L2_PIX_FMT_SN9C10X,
            V4L2_PIX_FMT_SBGGR8,
            V4L2_PIX_FMT_SGBRG8,
            V4L2_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
            V4L2_PIX_FMT_Y16
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(try_order) / sizeof(__u32); i++) {
        capture->palette = try_order[i];
        if (try_palette_v4l2(capture)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    fprintf(stderr,
            "VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV\n");
    icvCloseCAM_V4L(capture);
    return -1;
}
```